# Mysql count with condition

Tags: mysql, count

I have a table like this:

```
+---------------+--------+-----------------+
| ReservationID | UserID | ReservationDate |
+---------------+--------+-----------------+
|             1 |  10002 | 04_04_2016      |
|             2 |  10003 | 04_04_2016      |
|             3 |  10003 | 07_04_2016      |
|             4 |  10002 | 04_04_2016      |
|             5 |  10002 | 04_04_2016      |
|             6 |  10002 | 06_04_2016      |
+---------------+--------+-----------------+
```

I use this query to count how many reservation each of my user have:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(UserID) as Times FROM mytable GROUP BY UserID ORDER BY Times DESC
```

And It gives me this result:

```
+--------+-------+
| UserID | Times |
+--------+-------+
|  10002 |     4 |
|  10003 |     2 |
+--------+-------+
```

However I want to count one if my user has more than one reservation in specific date. For example User 10002 has 3 reservation at 04-04-2016, It should be count 1. And I want to get this result:

```
+--------+-------+
| UserID | Times |
+--------+-------+
|  10002 |     2 |
|  10003 |     2 |
+--------+-------+
```

How can I can get it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `count` with `distinct` instead:

```
SELECT UserID, COUNT(DISTINCT ReservationDate) as Times 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY UserID 
ORDER BY Times DESC
```

Comment: User 10002 has 3 reservation at 04-04-2016, It should be count 1. It means there should be relation on ReservationDate

Comment: @berkist34 -- sorry, typed too quickly.  I think you need `count(distinct reservationdate)`?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  m.UserID,
  count(distinct lj.ReservationDate) as Times 
FROM mytable m
  left join mytable lj on lj.UserID = m.UserId
GROUP BY 
  m.UserId
ORDER BY 
  Times
```

Comment: with this query, users get affected by other user's reservations which I don't want.  I don't want to count if one user has more than one reservation in a specific date